# How to add dynamic header in all the pages while generating pdf from XML using XSL:FO using fop?

Tags: xml, header, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have to generate a header that is dynamic and not static ,the value of which comes out from the xml file.I am using XSl:FO for generating pDF using XML.I want to add a section References to come in all the pages.

XSl File:

```
`<xsl:template match="References">
    <fo:block-container height="12cm" width="5cm" top="15mm" left="12cm" position="absolute">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-family="Verdana">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-
```

'

XML File:

```
            <Referentces>
                <lbl>Date</lbl>
                <div>$date</div>
                <lbl>From</lbl>
                <div>$brief.owner</div>
                <div>T $brief.tel</div>
                #if($brief.fax)
                <div>F $brief.fax</div>
                #end
              </Referenties>
```

How can i call this block to appear in all the pages automatically?

Comment: XSL file:   <xsl:template match="Referenties">
        <fo:block-container height="12cm" width="5cm" top="15mm" left="12cm" position="absolute">
            <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-family="Verdana">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: Where do you wish the content in question to appear in all the pages? If it is the header, see below. The same would apply for footer just using a different region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSL FO, you do not place a block-container absolute positioned to attempt to make repeating headers. It will only be placed on the page in which it occurs and not all pages.

You use static-content for xsl-region-before. So your page-sequence should look something like this:

```
 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
      <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
          <fo:block>This is content on every page</fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region--body">
          <!-- body content here -->
      </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
```

You can define the size of the header and body regions in the layout-master-set for the page-master in question.

Now, if you have dynamic content in that header that depends on the section/page you are in, then you use fo:marker and fo:retrieve-marker to pull that content from the page you are in into the header.

See http://www.renderx.com/tutorial.html#Markers for a tutorial on Markers and how you use them to pull information into the static regions.